# C++ interface DB access

Tags: c++, database, oop, interface, overloading

I am writing an non virtual interface with for the database, for now it looks like this

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H

#include <boost/core/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_whole_number(const std::string& s);

class db_interface : boost::noncopyable{
    
    public:
        void connect(std::string dbname, std::string host = "", std::string user = "", std::string password = "", std::string port ="")  {
            
            if (connect_to_DB(dbname, host, user, password, port))
                std::cout <<dbname<<": connected"<<'\n';
            else
                std::cout <<dbname<<": connection failed"<<'\n';
        }
        virtual ~db_interface(){};
    private:
        virtual bool connect_to_DB(std::string dbname, std::string host, std::string user, std::string password, std::string port)  = 0;
        
        
};

class postgreSQL : public db_interface{
    private:
        PGconn *conn;
        PGresult *res;
        std::string coninfo;
        bool connect_to_DB(std::string dbname, std::string host, std::string user, std::string password, std::string port = "5432")  {
            
            if (port.empty())
                port = "5432";
                    
            conn = PQsetdbLogin(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), "", " ",  dbname.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str());

            if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_OK)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    
};

class AnotherDB : public db_interface{
    private:
        bool connect_to_DB(std::string dbname, std::string host, std::string user, std::string password, std::string port)  {return false;}
};

#endif
```

And I have two questions: How can I overload the connect function in the base class for other DBs that don't need so many arguments, or have other argumens? And the second question is: is it possible to put the *conn pointer and other data I will have later, like records,  in the base class?

Comment: If the `connect()` function isn't common for all sub classes, why should it be in the base class?

Comment: @vahancho As I understand from the NVI ideom it is how it's done. Since it is public it is visible for all the other derived classes and it uses the virtual method connect_to_DB in this case.